# initrd not found error with virt-manager and Yocto generated image

Tags: virtual-machine, yocto, qemu, kvm

I'm trying to boot a Linux image built using Yocto under KVM using the virt-manager GUI. I'm using this guide:
https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Virtualization_with_KVM

I'm generating a .iso of a core-image inheriting custom image (and using this as existing drive) and selecting direct kernel boot with the kernel arg:
`root=/dev/hda (tried also /dev/sda)`

Bootup ends with a kernel panic due to no init found found, suggesting to pass `init=`  argument to kernel.

I'm able of running this image using qemu cli, but not in GUI. I've tried also other image formats such as `ext4` and `wic`, but all of them are unable to boot.

So, any idea on how to configure this thing?